# A double sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Any help in the following question is welcome. Let $a_{n,k}$ be a real double sequence such that:

1. $a_{n,k} = 0$ for all $k > n$, that is,

\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 & \ldots\\
    a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & 0 & \dots  & 0 & \ldots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
    a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \dots  & a_{n,n} & 0 & \ldots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{bmatrix}

2. $a_{n,1} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $a_{n,2} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$,..., $a_{n,n - 1} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and $a_{n,n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ (that is, for each $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1,n$, the convergence $a_{n,k} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ holds).

I'm trying to conclude that $\sup_{k \geq 1} a_{n,k} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Can this conclusion be false? If so what could be a counter-example? Thank you.

Comment: The second statement does not make sense: you are using $n$ both as a possible (fixed) value of $k$ and as a limit variable. Do you mean simply that for every fixed $k$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,k} = 0$? Consider the sequence where $a_{n,n}=1$ but all the other $a_{n,k}=0$.

Comment: It's a good exercise, but you will benefit more from trying to find an approach yourself rather than immediately turning to Math.SE for a solution.

Comment: No, $n$ will tend to infinity. The $k$ will vary between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: Hint: See if it is possible to have all ones on the diagonal of the "matrix" that represents the sequence.

Comment: @GregMartin's critique of the second numbered "statement" still has force after the recent edit, in which you've now added an assertion that $a_{n,n} \to 0$.  Perhaps the intention is to assert convergence to zero for *two* kinds of sequences, ones that run down columns (for fixed $k$) and ones that run parallel to the diagonal (i.e. $a_{n,n-k}$ for fixed $k$).  It will still be possible to find examples where $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{1\le k \le n} a_{n.k} = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the matrix defined this way: $$a_{n,k}=\begin{cases}1,& n=k+1\\0,&\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

This defines the following matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 & \ldots\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 & \ldots \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \dots  & 0 & \ldots \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \dots  & 0 & \dots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{bmatrix}$$

If we fix $k$ $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n,k}=0,$$ and the diagonal consists entirely of zeros, therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,n}\rightarrow 0$. We conclude that all requirements are met (i.e. columnwise elements are vanishing, row-wise elements are eventually 0, and diagonal is converging to $0$ as well).

We would like to compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge1}a_{n,k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\max\{a_{n,1}, a_{n,2},\ldots a_{n,n-1},0,0,...0\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\max\{0, 0,\ldots,1,0\}=1$$

This provides a counterexample.